# javascript add string to variable error

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript program that worked until I tried to change this: `"foldername"` to this: `http://hokuco.com/test/"+"foldername"+"/index.html"`.
what is wrong with my code?
For anyone interested entire JS:

```js
     document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(){
      var url = document.getElementById("http://hokuco.com/test/"+"foldername"+"/index.html").value;

      window.location.href = "url";
    });
```

```html
<input type id="foldername"></input>
<input type ="button" id ="submit/>
```

Comment: Well that would make for a very unusual ID. Do you understand what `.getElementById()` does? You also have quotes around `url`, so it's not going to use the variable, if that was your intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably meant:

```
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(){
  var url = "http://hokuco.com/test/" + document.getElementById("foldername").value + "/index.html";

  window.location.href = url;
});
```

Changes:

- The parameter in the `getElementById` function is the same as the id attribute on the input element with the id "foldername".
- The `window.location.href` should be set to a variable, not a quoted string.

More legibly, you would want:

```
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(){
  var folder = document.getElementById("foldername").value;
  var url = "http://hokuco.com/test/" + folder + "/index.html";

  window.location.href = url;
});
```

Now, hopefully, it is much more clear about what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the following documentation to better understand document.getElementById: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById
Your code will most likely return an uncaught type error when trying to access a property of null. You must only pass a string referring to an Element object's ID.

Comment: It is often helpful to provide a working example in your response and not only link the documentation.

Answer (score -2):

What are you trying to accomplish? It looks like you are trying to redirect but are using a string literal instead of a variable.